# Android Translucent status bar with Inverted icons

Tags: android, android-design-library

I was wondering how one could achieve Google Calendar's look.[image]

That is:

- Inverted status bar icons
- Custom status bar color(that is not the default color transparency set by windowTranslucentStatus)
- Widgets top padding adjusted to be under the status bar

**What I've tried:**

*Setting windowTranslucentStatus disables windowLightStatusBar:*

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

*Allows full transparency only(no colors in between), fitSystemWindows doesn't work properly:*

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">#19000000</item>

window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Managed to find the solution:

onCreate (in Kotlin):

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
window.statusBarColor = Color.parseColor("#1A000000")
```

styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for the values that can be set inside each XML attribute?

Answer (score 4):

Fixed this by setting all the flags programmatically. Apparently, for some weird reason setting the windowsLightStatusBar in styles wasn't reflecting.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccentDark));
        //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        //setStatusBarTranslucent(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change status bar icon color to black .add this in your values-v23/styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

eg.add this to your values-v23 folder in style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#F5F5F5</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

make sure to change colorPrimaryDark in v23/styles.xml to grey or white.it works from API 23

Comment: Setting just that option doesn't produce the results in the picture

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. add this in values-v23 and set this theme in your layout

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>
```

This will change the status bar background to white

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">#fff</item>
```

This will change status bar icon to invert(grey)

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Output will be like this, you can change your action bar color what ever you want I gave as blue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in Compose:

implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.30.1"

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

SideEffect {
        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(Color.Transparent, darkIcons = true)
        systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(navigationBarColor)
}
```